# How to get default selected radio button from radio group?

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I have a radio group consisting of three radio buttons `'yes'`,`'no'`,`'do not know'`. I am setting `android:checkedButton="@id/r3"` to default select to third radio button. I have set `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for the radio group and it gets called on selecting any radio button from UI.

I want to call the listener in `onCreate` for the default selected radio button because I am performing setting some values in code on default selected.

Is there any possibility to get the default selected radio button in radio group in `onCreate` and perform some actions, later `setOnCheckedChangeListener` will handle the selected radio button from UI

```
<RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/rg1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checkedButton="@id/r3"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/r1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Yes"
                        android:textColor="@color/fontBlackEnable" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/r2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="No"
                        android:textColor="@color/fontBlackEnable" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/r3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:text="@string/do_not_know" />

                </RadioGroup>
```

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    View rootView;
    Context context;
    RadioGroup mRadioAns3;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
        context = container.getContext();
        mRadioAns3 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rg1);

       //Todo: get default selected radiobutton and show toast on load of fragment


        mRadioAns3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                Toast.makeText(context,((RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(checkedId)).getText() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Comment: Just use _android:checked="true"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==-1)
{
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please select Gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
{
    // get selected radio button from radioGroup
    int selectedId = gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    // find the radiobutton by returned id
    selectedRadioButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
    Toast.makeText(mContext, selectedRadioButton.getText().toString()+" is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: `gender` is your `RadioGroup`

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
android:checkedButton="@+id/r3"
```

Instead of:

```
android:checkedButton="@id/r3"
```

And you can also use this:

```
radiogroup.check(radioButtonId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Boolean attribute `android:checked` is the helping property available in layout file,

Something like,

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgGender"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbMale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_male" 
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbFemale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_female" />
</RadioGroup>
```

NOTE : Assign this attribute to `RadioButton` you want to show selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the default selected button by its **ID**. RadioGroup supports the method which returns the **button id** of the default selected radio button.

In your case, The code is like

```
rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()
```

Please check android documentation for method.

[getCheckedRadioButtonId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup#getCheckedRadioButtonId())

Answer (score 0):

Radio group supports to find selected radio button id, Here your radio button is mRadioAns3 and you can get selected radio button id by,

```
int selectedRadioBtnID = mRadioAns3.getCheckedRadioButtonId ();
```

By using this id you can get selected radio button,

```
RadioButton radioBtn = mRadioAns3.findViewByID(selectedRadioBtnID);
```

From this radio button you can show toast message at loding,

```
Toast.makeText(context, radioBtn.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
```

Hope it will help you.